# Replicate SQL where column in clause With Snowpark and Python

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I figured out how to replicate simple where clauses with Snowpark such as:

sql:
`WHERE COL_NAME > 5`

Python:
`col(COL_NAME) > 5`

I don't know how to do in Snowpark:
`WHERE COL_NAME IN (1,2,3,4)`

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.

Here is a simple example:

```
df.filter(df["col_name"].in_(lit(1), lit(2), lit(3))).collect()
```

You can read more about this [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/api/snowflake.snowpark.Column.in_.html#snowflake-snowpark-column-in).